# Unable to cmd+click on Java method in Eclipse in Mountain Lion

Tags: android, eclipse, osx-mountain-lion

Yesterday I upgraded from Lion to Mountain Lion and today my productivity went down. I cannot perform "cmd + click" on a method or variable to go its declaration because the popup shown in eclipse contains a horizontal scrollbar which overflows the last option.

Does anyone have a solution how to fix this?

UPDATE: Just to be clear- neither "When Scrolling", nor "Automatically based on mouse or trackpad" options remove the problem for me. Only "Always" does work, but its consequences to the whole system UX are not acceptable

Comment: i would recommend changing operating system, but then people would call me a troll...

Answer (score 10):

Try doing this. In Mountain Lion, go to Preferences -> General and for `Show scroll bars` choose `Always` like so :

[image]

That should prevent the scroll bar from covering the last option and allow you to click it. Does this help ?

**Update**

I just checked that this indeed works. In fact for me it's only the `When Scrolling` option that creates a problem. With either of the remaining settings, things are peachy :

Unfortunately, I can't post a screen shot since the cmd + click popup disappears as soon as I press the shortcut key for taking a screenshot (Cmd + Shift + 4).

**Update 2**
I just made this quick screen cast to show the relation between the Mountain Lion Preferences and how it effects eclipse. Take a look at it **[here](http://youtu.be/qV7EmzozI0o)**.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. However on my Mac choosing "Automatically based..." option doesn't remove the issue in Eclipse. And the "Always" option is simply unacceptable and distracting. What version of Eclipse did you try it on? I'm testing on Juno right now. Update: just tried on Indigo - same problem

Comment: "Automatically based ..." option doesn't remove the issue for me too. Eclipse Juno

Answer (score 2):

If you press F3 while the cursor is on a variable or method then Eclipse will 'open declaration'. Fix the problem by removing the mouse-based workflow?

Comment: This is too painful to me, love my mouse :)